# Decode AAC bytestream on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, aac, decoder

I need to programmatically decode AAC bytestream (either raw AAC or with ADTS) into PCM on Windows Phone 8.1.

How can I do this? Are there any samples available that show how to decode raw audio?